# Redirect STDOUT and STDERR in exec()... without shell

Tags: perl, exec, stdout, stdin, stderr

I am attempting to use Perl5 to `fork()` a child process.  The child process should `exec()` another program, redirecting its `STDIN` to a named pipe, and `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to log files.  The parent process continues running in a loop, using `waitpid` and checking `$?` to restart the child in case it dies with non-zero exit status.

Perl documentation for the `exec()` function says:

> If there is more than one argument in LIST, this calls *execvp(3)* with the arguments in LIST. If there is only one element in LIST, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing (this is `/bin/sh -c` on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms). If there are no shell metacharacters in the argument, it is split into words and passed directly to `execvp`, which is more efficient. Examples:
>
> ```
> exec '/bin/echo', 'Your arguments are: ', @ARGV;
> exec "sort $outfile | uniq";
> ```

This sounds pretty cool, and I'd like to run my external program without an intermediary shell, as shown in these examples.  Unfortunately, I am unable to combine this with output redirection (as in `/bin/foo > /tmp/stdout`).

**In other words, this does not work:**

```
exec ( '/bin/ls', '/etc', '>/tmp/stdout' );
```

So, my question is: how do I redirect the `STD*` files for my sub-command, without using the shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redirection via `<` and `>` is a **shell feature**, which is why it does not work in this usage.  You are essentially calling `/bin/ls` and passing `>/tmp/stdout` as just another argument, which is easily visible when replacing the command by `echo`:

```
exec ('/bin/echo', '/etc', '>/tmp/stdout');
```

prints:

```
/etc >/tmp/stdout
```

Normally, your shell (`/bin/sh`) would have parsed the command, spotted the redirection attempts, opened the proper files, and also pruned the argument list going in to `/bin/echo`.

However -
A program started with `exec()` (or `system()`) will inherit the `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` files of its calling process.  So, the proper way to handle this is to

- close each special filehandle,
- re-open them, pointing at your desired logfile, and
- finally call `exec()` to start the program.

Rewriting your example code above, this works fine:

```
close STDOUT;
open (STDOUT, '>', '/tmp/stdout');
exec ('/bin/ls', '/etc');
```

...or, using the indirect-object syntax recommended by `perldoc`:

```
close STDOUT;
open (STDOUT, '>', '/tmp/stdout');
exec { '/bin/ls' } ('ls', '/etc');
```

(in fact, according to the documentation, this final syntax is the only reliable way to avoid instantiating a shell in Windows.)

Answer (score 4):

The following shell command tells the shell to launch `/bin/ls` with `/etc` for argument with its STDOUT redirected.

```
/bin/ls /etc >/tmp/stdout
```

On the other hand, the following Perl statement tells the Perl to replace the current program with `/bin/ls`, with `/etc` and `>/tmp/stdout` for arguments.

```
exec('/bin/ls', '/etc', '>/tmp/stdout');
```

You didn't tell Perl to redirect STDOUT at all! Remember `exec` doesn't start a new process, so if you change the child process's fd 1, it will effect `ls` running in the same process.

But rather than just fixing this one problem (as Greg Kennedy did) but leave your other problems intact (e.g. misreporting the inability of launching `ls` as an error from `ls`), I'll show you to fix them all:

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

my $stdout = '';
{
   # open3 will close the handle used as the child's STDIN.
   # open3 has issues with lexical file handles.
   open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;

   my $pid = open3('<&CHILD_STDIN', local *CHILD_STDOUT, '>&STDERR',
      '/bin/ls', '/etc');

   while (my $line = <CHILD_STDOUT>) {
      $stdout .= $line;
   }

   waitpid($pid, 0);
}
```

While that saved you a hundred lines of code, [`open3`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Open3) is a still quite low-level. (You'll run into problems if you have to deal with two pipes.) I instead recommend [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run3) (simpler) or [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run) (more flexible).

```
use IPC::Run3 qw( run3 );
run3([ '/bin/ls', '/etc' ], \undef, \my $stdout);
```

or

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );
run([ '/bin/ls', '/etc' ], \undef, \my $stdout);
```